# How to create a blinking effect in After Effects CC?

Tags: after-effects, animation, automation

What I want to do is simple conceptually, but I am just not having success with actually doing it.

I am creating a short video snippet in After Effects, as part of a larger presentation. The video is supposed to begin with a blinking light under the title, which then transitions, with a sound effect, to the video itself.

I've worked out the sound effect, the transition, and all of the other stuff - I just don't know how to animate a blinking light. There must be a way to automate turning the opacity on and off - but all of the tutorials I've found date from several years ago at the earliest and presuppose a working knowledge of After Effects that is more in-depth than what I have.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Preferably with explicit steps!

Answer (score 4):

1. Create your keyframes
2. Select them by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, via box select or simply click the *Flare Brightness Property*
3. Then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click the stopwatch icon, this will create an expression
4. Then click the *Expression Arrow* <kbd>></kbd> and select *Property >  `loopoutduration`* this will cause that the keyframes to repeat themselves

[image]

Comment: I very much appreciate the pictures. Thanks to them, I was able to immediately get it to do what I wanted. I wish After Effects was more clear on how things interacted, though I guess I'll get a feel for it after spending more time with it.

Comment: @LukeMayson should mark this the correct answer, helps Video get out of Beta.